# How do I stemm two words and join them to look for them in stemming file - python

Tags: python-3.x, text, stemming

I have a code to research on a stemming word in a stemming file,
but I want also to stem two words then join them and look for them in stemming file, if I do it by this code give me a empty result, How can I edit it?

```
  keywordsssss = (stemmer.stemWord("company name")) mergeddf.pop(0)
 list_of_text = [] for i in mergeddf:
     if keywordsssss in i:
         list_of_text.append(i) keyword={} for i in list_of_text:
     # list = i.split("", 2)
     list = re.split("([^ ]+[ ]+[^ ]+)[ ]",i)
     for y in list:
         if y in keyword:
             keyword[y] +=1
         else:
             keyword[y] = 1
```

Comment: Could you give examples of your expected output for some inputs?

Comment: the output : the frequency of each word that appears with the keywordsssss which are two words